# How can I set the text box as editable when its document mode is readonly in xpages?

Tags: xpages, xpages-ssjs

To set the edit text as editable when the document mode is readOnly.
I add the following code at edit box's readOnly as Computed Field.

```
var fruitName= sessionScope.get("fruitName");
if(fruitName.equals("Apple") | fruitName.equals("Orange")){
    return false;
}else{
    return true;
}
```

But the code doesn't work.

Comment: fruitName.equals("Apple") & fruitName.equals("Orange") is always false, right?

Comment: David Javarre ......No.The main problem is I couldn't change the edit box into editable mode when the current document mode is readOnly.

Comment: But since fruitName could only be equal to either "Apple" or "Orange", the statement would always be false, in addition to the other issue.

Comment: Thanks David Javarre...... I need to change "&" AND operator to "|" OR operator. If you know about XPages language, could you give any suggestion or idea about "Only when document mode is READONLY mode and I want to change the edit box into EDITABLE mode in a specific condition". I think the main thing is that the document mode is readOnly that why I could not change the edit box into readOnly mode. May I know what is your suggestion and how to solve it.

Comment: I'd put the document in edit mode, with div's marking the rest of the document as readonly, so you can edit and save that field. The other way would be to have the value only changed on the back end, but that would be jumping through hoops and might lead to some unexpected rep-save conflicts.

Answer (score 2):

Connect your input text field with a **scope variable** instead of a document's field.

```xml
<xp:inputText 
    id="inputText1" 
    value="#{viewScope.editField}"
    readonly="#{javascript:...}">
</xp:inputText>
```

By default it will be editable.
You can still compute the readonly property.
You can set a default value for scope variable from a document's fields and you can do with the edited value whatever you want like writing back to current or other document.